# Use Proxy to run application in Android Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, http-get

Has anybody managed to get the Android Emulator working behind a proxy?
I have tried the following solutions :

- Set the Proxy in Eclipse.
- Set the proxy in emulator in "Settings" -> "Wireless & Networks" -> "Mobile Networks" -> "Access Point Names" -> "Telkila" .
- Have also tried passing the --http-proxy parameters while launching the emulator.
- Combination of above mentioned things.

But nothing worked for me.

Any Solution to this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the proxy from your code?

Comment: @RanhiruCooray I have tried specifying proxy inside by code,but no success. Logically this should not be the solution, I want to create a general app, that should work well in direct/proxy environment.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `--http-proxy` parameter definitely works (you can add it to Eclipse' default emulator options). Check that you have set the correct port and username/password if your proxy requires authentication.